# GeoTIFF to ENVI GDAL translation causes rotation

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate, envi

I have a GeoTIFF([you can download it here ~16MB)](https://we.tl/t-USiwQvUADO) which I want to convert to [ENVI raw](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/envi.html). I'm using this GDAL command:
`gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -scale -of ENVI -outsize 1025 1025 dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.tif dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.raw`
The command runs fine, but gives a warning:
`Warning 1: Geotransform matrix has non rotational terms`

When I compare the *.tif and the *.raw file in QGIS (3.14), the *.raw file got somehow rotated.
So I did some googling and found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229952/rotate-envi-hyperspectral-imagery-with-gdal).
Ok, let's have look:
`grep "map info" dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.hdr` gives:
`map info = {Transverse Mercator, 1, 1, 32371999.5, 5679999.5, 1.95121951219512, 1.95121951219512, rotation=90}`

But according to [this blog post](https://capstone-coal.github.io/2017/04/30/gdal-envi-rotation-bug-fix.html) the bug have been fixed with GDAL 2.20. I'm using GDAL 3.0.4.
So does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Test image would be appreciated. The data in the image is not interesting, just the georeferencing, so if your image is confidential try to add the same georeference to any other image.

Comment: I've added a download link to the *.tif image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to gdalwarp to fix the rotation:

```
gdalwarp -of VRT dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.tif dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.vrt

Creating output file that is 2000P x 2000L.
Processing input file dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.tif.

gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -scale -of ENVI -outsize 1025 1025 dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.vrt dgm1_32372_5680_2_nw.raw

Input file size is 2000, 2000
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Comment: I wonder if QGIS Still should  be able to rotate the image correctly on-the-fly. It can when the images are georeferenced with ground control points. This solution feels like a workaroud: if ENVI driver cannot handle the rotated input, make it unrotated with gdalwarp first.

Comment: @user30184 I agree.

Comment: Just FYI: ArcGIS Pro behaves the same. The image is displayed somehow rotated. I also noticed a small mistake by myself. I will need to use `-scale 0 255 0 65535` to make use of the whole 16bit range, or am I wrong here?

Comment: Only if your max value is 65535.  If you leave it blank, GDAL will compute the range. If your max value is say 10000, you could use `-scale 0 10000 0 255` note your order was incorrect.  You can play around withe the values to apply different stretches (i.e calc 2 & 98th percentile, or mean +- 2std) just like QGIS/ArcGIS stretches to symbolize.